# What build type use for distribution?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm creating the build of my iOS app to distribute it.
Actually I 'Build for Archive', I Archive it, Validate and then Submit.

What are the differences between the different kind of Build command?
What's the best solution for distribution? I have to use Build or Build for Archive?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the "Project" drop down menu just choose "Archive" it will build it and archive it all in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to build and archive so that you can submit your application through organizer. Once archived you can go into organizer and validate and submit your application bundle for App Store℠ approval.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. But it's best use "Build" or "Build for Archive" ?